# Changing the value of a float field

Tags: nodes, entities

I wrote PHP code that sums floating point values.
The problem with it is that the field value ("field_money") changes by itself anytime.

```
$total = (float) ([node:field_emp_salary1]+[node:field_emp_mobile]+[node:field_emp_reward]+[node:field_emp_mission]+[node:field_emp_compensation])-([node:field_emp_paycut]+[node:field_emp_advance]);
$total = number_format($total, 2);
$nid = 134;
$node = node_load($nid);
$balance = $node->field_pbalance['und']['0']['value'];

if ($total > $balance) {
  print  $total;
  echo "There is a problem.";
}
else {
  print $total;
  $balance = $balance-$total;
  $node->field_pbalance['und']['0']['value'] = $balance;
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: this is a php problem/question, not a drupal one, but I'd throw in a `print $total;` and or `print $balance;` in there to figure out what's going on since you first set `$total` to a casted `float` with some crazy (uninitialized?) php in your first line, then setting it into a `string` via `number_format()` and then comparing (`>`) it to `$balance` later on whose initial type is unknown to us here without further information (I assume `float`)... which makes me think your `if` is always failing regardless of what you think `$total` and `$balance` really are...

Comment: Also, the code you shown doesn't use any "field_money" field you are referring in the text of your question.

Comment: sory i make a mistake the field_money is field_pbalance.  
field_money is for another content type but the problem is the same